# SVG Linked from same svg file causes one to disappear

Tags: html, svg

Strange one this.

I've got the following:

```
<svg aria-hidden="true">
   <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#down"></use>
</svg>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <svg aria-hidden="true">
                <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close"></use>
            </svg>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The first icon doesn't show up. However if I change the svg file of the first to:

```
<svg aria-hidden="true">
   <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#down"></use>
</svg>
```

Then both show, is there something I'm missing with SVG from the same file?

It's definitely not a URL thing, because if both `<svg>` tags use the same URL, then only the second is displayed.

Many Thanks

Comment: The symptoms would suggest that the file "/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg" does not contain any elements with id "down".  Are you sure it is supposed to?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau unfortunately if i just copy/paste the two snippets the first one disappears. It's almost like the external svg file is being cached or something and it's not allowing 2 different elements to use the same icon.. It's really strange!

Comment: Ok, if I just paste the contents of the external file into my HTML and use #close or #down - it works, so it's something to do with the fact that I'm using an external file

Comment: "If i just copy/paste the two snippets the first one disappears". Then you should modify your question to make that clear.  Ideally create a Plunkr or something to show the problem.

Comment: I've made the edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HOPE THIS HELPS TO ALL NEW PEOPLE

After all this years I stumbled upon the same problem and I solved it...
What happened for  me was that the fill attributes of my paths shared the same url(#paint0_linear) and the viewbox of these "fill" where set on the position of the first SVG in the DOM, to solve this just change the name of the fills (and their corresponding id's) of the subsequent SVGS.

English is not my native language so let me show you what I did in code in case I didn't make myself clear:

```
<svg width="32" height="24" viewBox="0 0 32 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g id="hamb1">
          <path id="hambBottom1" fillRule="evenodd" clipRule="evenodd" d="M0 22" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
          <path id="hambTop1" d="M13.8599" fill="url(#paint1_linear)"/>
        </g>
        <defs>
          <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="-6.5" y1="30" x2="18.9429" y2="34.8415" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop stopColor="#134F82"/>
            <stop offset="1" stopColor="#2BA665"/>
          </linearGradient>
          <linearGradient id="paint1_linear" x1="-6.50012" y1="30" x2="18.9428" y2="34.8414" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop stopColor="#134F82"/>
            <stop offset="1" stopColor="#2BA665"/>
          </linearGradient>
        </defs>
      </svg>
```

Check that the **fill** attribute on the paths **NEVER** share the **same id.**

Comment: Cracking find! Have marked as the answer... 5 years later :D

Answer (score -2):

I can't be completely sure since I guess you should explain question properly, But it may be the case that first file path may not be correct (ie with link "/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#down") (ie may be some spell error) so the file is not loading. Try loading file manually with url.

Comment: The file clearly exists because it loads just fine in the second SVG.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau sorry didn't see that thing clearly, but I am just a beginner don't downvote me at least.